# Google Hangout "insecure content" although files are 'https'

Tags: javascript, ssl, google-plus, google-hangouts

I followed this tutorial and have downloaded the exact same files (I adapted my url's): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Al4SbeVyLm4

When I want to start the hangout with the app my chrome console is saying me this:

```
[blocked] The page at 'https://hangoutsapi.talkgadget.google.com/hangouts/_/g4iaptmji5625clcowcybzi3iua?authuser=0' 
was loaded over HTTPS, but ran insecure content from
'http://www.example.com/hangout-app-tut/helpdesk-sample.html?parent=https…wt-qr9MmqJHwh-acNDV9hK8zEUZmIWHE2QyIcB_nHj6AgDbXA1NNC44w1E984&gd=50':
this content should also be loaded over HTTPS.
```

My server has a verified ssl certificate (test certificate) and is accessible by 'https'.  All the url's specified in the different files are beginning with 'https', so I have no idea why this error is happening.  I double-checked all files.

Or is it because my website just runs on a 'test certificate', but I guess, this can not be the issue.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: The console is telling you about problems with [mixed content](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-mixed-content-20140722/): *"http ://www.example.com/hangout-app-tut/helpdesk-sample.html..."*. Why are you trying to make an HTTP fetch instead of a HTTPS fetch?

Comment: I just solved the issue.  The problem was my htaccess file which always redirect to "http://www..."